# cursor control for a text block while entering data via keyboard

Tags: wpf

I have a text block which I have binded to a data field in my c# code which has a setter and getter.

I can enter numbers fine into the text block via the keyboard
The c# code can also set the text value.

I have seen this weird problem where I starting typing a number and I think at the same time the text field is being set by the setter.  This causes the cursor to jump from the right where I'm typing to the left, so while I'm typing the number the what I type is not what is seen in the text block. This is because the cursor jumped locations in the middle of me typing.  Is there any way to control the cursor so it's always at the right???

Here is an example.
I want to type 1234

- I'll type 12 (cursor at right)
- I think at this point another of the code will echo the same value 12 and set it.
- Then the cursor will jump to the left
- then I will finish typing 34
- The final value will be 3412

Thank you very much for any ideas!!

Answer (score 0):

- try to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`, to prevent updating the source too often.
- check your Property-Setter if `RaisePropertyChanged` is only called when the new value differs from the old property-value.

Comment: I don't have any triggers set up. How would I do that?